# Is possible to make Pantheon snap windows like Windows 10?

Tags: gala, pantheon, window-manager, camera

When you drag the window corner, other window on the side will fill the free space, is possible to make something like this with Pantheon/Gala?

[image: windows 10 snap]

Answer (score 2):

This functionality has been finally added with elementary OS 5.0 Juno.